# Angular 2 error Error: Type dataGrid is part of the declarations of 2 modules(same module): DataGridModule and DataGridModule

Tags: angular

I have many feature modules which imports DataGridModule. When I traverse such that when one feature module is loaded and navigate to another feature module, I get the below error,

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type dataGrid is part of the
>   declarations of 2 modules: DataGridModule and DataGridModule! Please
>   consider moving dataGrid to a higher module that imports
>   DataGridModule and DataGridModule. You can also create a new NgModule
>   that exports and includes dataGrid then import that NgModule in
>   DataGridModule and DataGridModule.

DataGridModule:

```
import {Compiler, Component,NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }   from '@angular/common';
import {dataGrid} from './dataGrid';
import { DataTableModule,SharedModule,DataScrollerModule } from 'primeng/primeng';

@NgModule({
      imports: [DataTableModule,SharedModule,DataScrollerModule,CommonModule],
      declarations: [dataGrid],
      entryComponents: []  ,
      exports:[dataGrid]
    })

export class DataGridModule { }
```

Zone.Module.ts

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {SharedFormModule} from '../../../../../../../UMSToolkit/UIToolkit/shared/shared-form.module';
import {DataGridModule} from '../../../../../../../UMSToolkit/UIToolkit/xdata/view/datagrid.module';
import {ZoneRoutingModule} from './Zone-routing.module';
import {RevertModule} from '../../shared/Revert.module'

@NgModule({
    imports:      [SharedFormModule,DataGridModule,ZoneRoutingModule,RevertModule],
    declarations: [],
    bootstrap:    [ ],
    entryComponents: [],
    providers: []
  })

  export class ZoneModule { }
```

BasicDataGrid module

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {DataGridModule} from '../../../../../../../../UMSToolkit/UIToolkit/xdata/view/dataGrid.module';
import {BasicDataGridComponent} from './basic-datagrid.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [DataGridModule,CommonModule],
    declarations: [BasicDataGridComponent]
})
export class BasicDataGridModule
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was the typo error with case. Notice that BasicGridComponent was have dataGrid.module with a capital G causing the issue.

Thanks,